# Implementing Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image]

Any idea why am I getting this compilation error?

in one of those xml file there is :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/abs__bright_foreground_holo_dark"/> <!-- not selected -->
</selector>
```

Comment: try cleaning your projrct

Comment: You'll need to go into Eclipse's Error view and see what it says.

Comment: You should post some of the errors you get into the XML files, if I can guess, it's because you modified all the other folders containing styles and whatnot that those XMLs use, like this one `android:color="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark` for example.

Comment: I don't understand how @color/abs__bright_forground_holo_dark is there when i don't see it in the "color" folder

Comment: if i remember well, colors can be defined in the values/strings.xml file either

Comment: im still facing a problem in implementing sherlock ... anyone can provide me with a clear and simple guide on how to do it? thank you